# Display ul when hovering div:after

Tags: css, hover, block, display

I am trying to display `ul` when hovering over the arrow generated by `div:after`. How can I implement this?

```css
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.select-wrapper:after {
  content: "\25BC";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <span>Select an option</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item-1</li>
    <li>Item-2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When the mouse is over the arrow, I'd like to display the items.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is not possible with a pseudo class like :after. Either you create an additional element for the arrow, or you just use the wohle select element.

```css
.select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.select-wrapper:after {
    content: "\25BC";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
}
.select-wrapper ul {
  display: none;
}
.select-wrapper:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <span>Select an option</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item-1</li>
    <li>Item-2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Update:** pinpoint the arrow

```css
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #000;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
}
.arrow ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.arrow:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <span>Select an option</span>
  <div class="arrow">
    <ul>
      <li>Item-1</li>
      <li>Item-2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but the hovering is all over the wrapper div. Is any way to pinpoint the arrow?

Comment: I've updated my answer, there is now a seecond solution with pinpoint the arrow.

Comment: Yes, it works. May I get that arrow as a chevron down?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I can use the class arrow to make a chevron down 'V' but what I'd like to achieve is  to use a chevron down 'V' in the content of the after as it seems simpler to work on. Anyway, many thanks.